# How to efficiently derive new variables based on separating values that contain key-value pairs?

Tags: r, performance, tidyr

## Question

How can I efficiently derive new variables based on values of a data frame that contain key-value pairs (e.g. `ensembl_end_phase=-1`)?

The name of the variable should be the key and the content should be the value. I look for something like `tidyr::separate`, where the `into: Names of new variables to create as character vector` vector is dynamically created based on the observed keys.

## Application: Get Tidy Data Frame From Gene Annotation Files

I want to have a tidy `R` data frame for [GTF/GFF3 gene files](http://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html) used in genetic analyses.

Here is an example for the such a file (tab-delimiter):

```
seqname source  feature start   end score   strand  frame   attribute
1   havana  three   191356960   191356995   .   -   .   Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925
1   havana  exon    191357792   191357851   .   -   .   Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925;Name=ENSMUSE00001336486;constitutive=0;ensembl_end_phase=-1;ensembl_phase=-1;exon_id=ENSMUSE00001336486;rank=4;version=1
1   havana  three   191357792   191357851   .   -   .   Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925
1   havana  three   191358925   191359076   .   -   .   Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925
15  ensembl CDS__   98186839    98187790    .   -   1   ID=CDS:ENSMUSP00000132237;Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000165379;protein_id=ENSMUSP00000132237
```

Since these files can easily contain millions of rows, an efficient approach is crucial.

The files can be efficiently read using `read_delim` from the `readr` package. Now I struggle with creating variables based on the key-value pairs in the `attribute` column.

My usual approach would be applying `tidyr::separate` like this:

```
annotation %>% separate(attribute, into, sep = ";")
```

This fails, because the key-value pairs differ between rows. Hence, the *into* vector has to be dynamically created for each row. Since the keys are also not standardized between different sources of GTF/GFF files, there is no way of knowing the key names prior of processing them.

I want to do something like `tidyr::separate` but with variable names derived from the first word of the value (the key), which is derived by separating *attribute* at ";".

Can you give me a hint on how to do achieve this? Parsing all values individually using a for loop is *way* too slow.

Comment: Did you try `splitstackshape::cSplit`? or is that too inefficient? i.e. `cSplit(annotation, 'attribute', sep = ';', 'long')`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
library(tidyr)
lst <- lapply(strsplit(df$attribute, ";", T), strsplit, "=", T)
df$att <- lapply(lst, function(x) setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, x), c("key", "value")) )
df <- unnest(df)

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 14 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ seqname  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ source   : chr  "havana" "havana" "havana" "havana" ...
#  $ feature  : chr  "three" "exon" "exon" "exon" ...
#  $ start    : int  191356960 191357792 191357792 191357792 191357792 191357792 191357792 191357792 191357792 191357792 ...
#  $ end      : int  191356995 191357851 191357851 191357851 191357851 191357851 191357851 191357851 191357851 191357851 ...
#  $ score    : chr  "." "." "." "." ...
#  $ strand   : chr  "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
#  $ frame    : chr  "." "." "." "." ...
#  $ attribute: chr  "Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925" "Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925;Name=ENSMUSE00001336486;constitutive=0;ensembl_end_phase=-1;ensembl_phase=-1;exon_id=ENSMU"| __truncated__ "Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925;Name=ENSMUSE00001336486;constitutive=0;ensembl_end_phase=-1;ensembl_phase=-1;exon_id=ENSMU"| __truncated__ "Parent=transcript:ENSMUST00000191925;Name=ENSMUSE00001336486;constitutive=0;ensembl_end_phase=-1;ensembl_phase=-1;exon_id=ENSMU"| __truncated__ ...
#  $ key      : chr  "Parent" "Parent" "Name" "constitutive" ...
#  $ value    : chr  "transcript:ENSMUST00000191925" "transcript:ENSMUST00000191925" "ENSMUSE00001336486" "0" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splitstackshape` package for this,

```
library(splitstackshape)
fun1 <- function(x){
  dd1 <- cSplit(x, 'attribute', sep = ';', 'long')
  dd2 <- cSplit(dd1, 'attribute', sep = '=', 'wide', drop = FALSE)
  return(dd2)
}

fun1(df)
```

Comparing `system.time`,

```
df1 <- df[rep(row.names(df), 100000),]

fun_lukeA <- function(x, var) {
  lst <- lapply(strsplit(var, ";", T), strsplit, "=", T)
  x$att <- lapply(lst, function(x) setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, x), c("key", "value")))
  unnest(x)
}

system.time(fun_lukeA(df1, df1$attribute))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 296.89    0.36  298.15 

system.time(fun1(df1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   9.16    0.00    9.20
```